# Are the messengers in this hadith Muslim? What is the authenticity?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

Regarding this narrative:

> According to Tabari, also recorded by Abu Zuhra in his biography of the Prophet (pbuh) “Khaatam al-Nabiyyeen”, when Bazaam (the deputy of Kisraa in Yemen) sent two of his messengers to the Prophet (pbuh) in response to the Prophet (pbuh)’s letter to Kisraa, the Prophet (pbuh) looked at them with disgust, as they had shaved off their beards and had grown big moustaches. Thus, the Prophet (pbuh) asked these messengers what had prompted them to such appearance, to which they responded that it was according to the directives of their Lord (the king). The Prophet (pbuh) in return said that my Lord (God) has ordained growing the beard and trimming the moustaches.

Comment: They are messengers from a foreign king in a time when Islam hadn't spread outside the Arabian Peninsula and they called their king their "Lord." It seems evident that they are not Muslims.

Comment: @The Z Well “Lord” can refer to a master/ruler as well. Do you have any source for the first part of your answer? Thanks!

Comment: The word in Arabic is "Rabb" I believe, and Muslims aren't allowed to call anyone except Allah that. As for source, please read up on the letters the Prophet sent. They were sent before even Makkah was conquered. Obviously, Islam hadn't spread to Persia then.

Comment: In Arabic it is common to call the father (and husband) Rabb al-Bayt رب البيت (Lord of the house). And scholars said Pharaoh when addressing his people called him self their highest Lord saying أنا ربكم الأعلى, but didn't reach the ultimate arrogance to call himself with a stronger of Allah's attributes. As Rabb refers to anyone who is in charge and cares for his people.

Comment: Was anyone able to find information on the authenticity of this narrative?